# Twitter Bootstrap + datepicker + display the calendar in the screen

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, calendar, datepicker

I am using Twitter Bootstrap Datepicker and i want to always display the calendar in the screen, like the following example.

Somebody knows a way to do this?

Thanks!

[image: Datepicker opened in the screen]

Comment: Take a look at the generated code, and apply CSS to it. The provided CSS file (calendar.css) sets a lot of rules, and the rest (display:none, for instance), is set in JavaScript.

Use "inspect element" to see where the styles come from, and correct/override them appropriately.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16902808/975520

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `bootstrap-calendar` plugin and style it using its simple css to fit your needs.

Project site and docs: https://github.com/ahmontero/bootstrap-calendar

Demo page: http://ahmontero.github.io/bootstrap-calendar/

Answer (score 0):

You create an input field that is hidden, call the datepicker on that input field, call the `show` action on the datepicker and then add a little CSS to hide the small white arrow at the top of the datepicker div.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
     $("#foo").datepicker();
     $("#foo").datepicker("show");
  });
</script>

<style>
  #foo {
    display:none;
  }
  .datepicker:before, .datepicker:after {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<input id="foo"/>
```

[JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/S6g8B/).